# Kill graphical interface by button combination and switch to terminal

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, osx-server

I need to kill x window system on mac (I'm linux user, I don't know how called graphical interface on mac, I need to switch from graphical interface to terminal) by a button combination.

Are there any button combination to do it?

Comment: Not a programming question - belongs on http://apple.stackexchange.com

Comment: Hmm.. I'm sorry, I don't know about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two alternatives:

1. reboot in single user mode - hold down <kbd>Command</kbd> +
   <kbd>S</kbd> when rebooting
2. if you have login method set to user name + password then
   type `>console` as the user name and no password